# Add visibility effect to images in Java JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm using Java's JFrame to show a `.jpeg` image. I need to start horizontal sliding effect to an image when a checkbox is selected. So basically when the checkbox is selected, the image will start sliding from left to right, taking a few seconds and when finished, start again forever until the checkbox is unchecked. How can I add I this feature?

**EDIT**: Actually I do not mean the picture itself is moving; I mean the picture is stable and static, but the image will start to get visible with a horizontal sliding effect, from left to right and restart. I hope it is clear enough.

Assume here is my code to show images and checkboxes (got from Java tutorial):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/*
 * CheckBoxDemo.java requires 16 image files in the images/geek
 * directory: 
 * geek-----.gif, geek-c---.gif, geek--g--.gif, geek---h-.gif, geek----t.gif,
 * geek-cg--.gif, ..., geek-cght.gif.
 */
public class CheckBoxDemo extends JPanel
                          implements ItemListener {
    JCheckBox chinButton;
    JCheckBox glassesButton;
    JCheckBox hairButton;
    JCheckBox teethButton;

    /*
     * Four accessory choices provide for 16 different
     * combinations. The image for each combination is
     * contained in a separate image file whose name indicates
     * the accessories. The filenames are "geek-XXXX.gif"
     * where XXXX can be one of the following 16 choices.
     * The "choices" StringBuffer contains the string that
     * indicates the current selection and is used to generate
     * the file name of the image to display.

       ----             //zero accessories

       c---             //one accessory
       -g--
       --h-
       ---t

       cg--             //two accessories
       c-h-
       c--t
       -gh-
       -g-t
       --ht

       -ght             //three accessories
       c-ht
       cg-t
       cgh-

       cght             //all accessories
     */

    StringBuffer choices;
    JLabel pictureLabel;

    public CheckBoxDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        //Create the check boxes.
        chinButton = new JCheckBox("Chin");
        chinButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        chinButton.setSelected(true);

        glassesButton = new JCheckBox("Glasses");
        glassesButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_G);
        glassesButton.setSelected(true);

        hairButton = new JCheckBox("Hair");
        hairButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        hairButton.setSelected(true);

        teethButton = new JCheckBox("Teeth");
        teethButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        teethButton.setSelected(true);

        //Register a listener for the check boxes.
        chinButton.addItemListener(this);
        glassesButton.addItemListener(this);
        hairButton.addItemListener(this);
        teethButton.addItemListener(this);

        //Indicates what's on the geek.
        choices = new StringBuffer("cght");

        //Set up the picture label
        pictureLabel = new JLabel();
        pictureLabel.setFont(pictureLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));
        updatePicture();

        //Put the check boxes in a column in a panel
        JPanel checkPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        checkPanel.add(chinButton);
        checkPanel.add(glassesButton);
        checkPanel.add(hairButton);
        checkPanel.add(teethButton);

        add(checkPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(pictureLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
    }

    /** Listens to the check boxes. */
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        int index = 0;
        char c = '-';
        Object source = e.getItemSelectable();

        if (source == chinButton) {
            index = 0;
            c = 'c';
        } else if (source == glassesButton) {
            index = 1;
            c = 'g';
        } else if (source == hairButton) {
            index = 2;
            c = 'h';
        } else if (source == teethButton) {
            index = 3;
            c = 't';
        }

        //Now that we know which button was pushed, find out
        //whether it was selected or deselected.
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            c = '-';
        }

        //Apply the change to the string.
        choices.setCharAt(index, c);

        updatePicture();
    }

    protected void updatePicture() {
        //Get the icon corresponding to the image.
        ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon(
                                    "images/geek/geek-"
                                    + choices.toString()
                                    + ".gif");
        pictureLabel.setIcon(icon);
        pictureLabel.setToolTipText(choices.toString());
        if (icon == null) {
            pictureLabel.setText("Missing Image");
        } else {
            pictureLabel.setText(null);
        }
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = CheckBoxDemo.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckBoxDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new CheckBoxDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Can someone help me with that?"*  Specifically what do you mean by that?  For example, here it reads like 'Can someone finish this for me?'.  To which the answer would be 'VTC and a down vote'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to roll your own using something like a `javax.swing.Timer`, for example...

[image: Fly baby, fly]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SlidingAnimation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SlidingAnimation();
    }

    public SlidingAnimation() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;
        private int x = 0;

        private Timer timer;
        private long startTime = -1;
        private int playTime = 4000;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    float progress = 0f;
                    if (startTime == -1) {
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    } else {
                        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long diff = currentTime - startTime;

                        if (diff >= playTime) {
                            diff = 0;
                            startTime = -1;
                        }
                        progress = diff / (float)playTime;
                    }

                    x = (int)((getWidth() - img.getWidth()) * progress);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(img.getWidth() * 2, img.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is a two second loop, which calculates the current position based on the difference between a start time and the current time and the total area that the animation needs to move.  This does make it flexible, but it is a straight linear animation, it does not have the nice ease-in and ease-out which gives animation a more realistic movement...

For more advanced animation effects, I would strongly encourage you have a look at

- [The Timing Framework](https://java.net/projects/timingframework).  Provides good access to the core to do unusual things, but also has the ability to change an objects properties over time
- [Trident](https://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home). Provides the ability to change the properties of objects over time
- [Universal Tween Engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/) which I haven't used but looks really good.

You might also want to take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how custom painting is done in Swing

**Updated**

So, if I understand your comments, you want to do a cross fade effect.  Now there are a few ways to do this, you could use `BufferedImage#subImage` to get a "cropped" version of the original image and show that, but that, IMHO, doesn't produce such a nice effect...

Instead, you could use a masking technique which allows you to produce a fading effect...

[image]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SlidingAnimation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SlidingAnimation();
    }

    public SlidingAnimation() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        private Timer timer;
        private long startTime = -1;
        private int playTime = 4000;

        private float progress;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (startTime == -1) {
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    } else {
                        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long diff = currentTime - startTime;

                        if (diff >= playTime) {
                            diff = 0;
                            startTime = -1;
                        }
                        progress = diff / (float) playTime;
                    }

                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        protected BufferedImage generateImage() {

            BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = buffer.createGraphics();
            g2d.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
            g2d.clearRect(0, 0, buffer.getWidth(), buffer.getHeight());
            g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);

            float startAt = progress - 0.05f;
            float endAt = progress + 0.05f;

            if (endAt <= 0.1f) {
                startAt = 0;
                endAt = Math.max(0.1f, progress);
            } else if (endAt >= 1f) {
                endAt = 1f;
                startAt = progress;
            }

            LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                    new Point2D.Float(0, 0),
                    new Point2D.Float(img.getWidth(), 0),
                    new float[]{startAt, endAt},
                    new Color[]{new Color(0, 0, 0, 0), Color.RED});

            g2d.setPaint(lgp);

            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstOut.derive(1f));
            g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
            g2d.dispose();

            return buffer;

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(generateImage(), x, y, this);

                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good info. Actually I did not mean the picture itself is moving; I meant the picture is stable and static, but the image will start to get visible with a horizontal sliding effect, from left to right and restart. I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: You mean you want to fade the image in from left to right?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your picture. However in your picture the right-end of the image is faded smoothly, not sharp, while I was thinking a sharp sliding edge.

Comment: So I would favor removing the fade end if that makes the code simpler!

Comment: Then you could simply use `BufferedImage#subImage`, something like `img.subImage(0, 0, (int)(img.getWidth() * progress), img.getHeight)` and draw the resulting image...but it won't be as awesome ;)

Comment: I see. So I'll try to keep this. To be honest I'm a bit lost in the code! So I have a stupid question: Can you kindly help what I should do if I need to add this to a specific panel inside my frame contentPane (as opposed to a stand-alone application)?

Comment: You would use the `TestPane` (hopefully naming it something more descriptive) and add it to whatever panel you want.  You might like to supply a `setImage` and/or constructor that can take an `BufferedImage` reference to make it easier to use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63000/discussion-between-tina-jasmin-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: I have a generic question. Imagine this image is a long heart rate strip. So along with effect, we also want to move the window of the image (which is currently shown under this effect) a bit towards left. Can you kindly help me how to do that?

Comment: Do the effects move independently?  This is not simple solution.  You would have to use a combination of `subImage` and the masking technique I originally presented.

Comment: Ummm, I see. I did something using drawimg() given the x and y coordinate of the rectangle to be shown. However, it is not perfect.